# Laravel + Docker все в одном образе на проде?

Tags: laravel, docker

Я понимаю, что политика докера **1** процесс на **1** контейнер. Хотелось бы узнать что будет, какие могут быть последствия, если все сделать в одном образе и запустить один контейнер на проде, в нем supervisor c **php-fpm**, **queue:work** **schedule:work**, **websockets:serve**, все приложение в одном. БД, redis, и nginx c фронтом соответственно в своих контейнерах. Масштабирование не требуется. Имеет ли право на жизнь в проде такой подход?

Comment: Никаких, кроме как: если упадет контейнер, упадет всё полностью (и супервизор не спасет), и масштабировать это будет невозможно. Идея в целом на практике не используется, либо в случае простейших сайтов